# Change Exposed Filter from Dropdown to List

Tags: views

How can one change an exposed filter format so it is displayed as a list rather than a dropdown list? If it is relevant, I am using the Better Exposed Filters module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to BEF settings in the view....

[image]

Find your exposed filter, and choose the display type. (list)

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I discover that I have filters that display as dropdowns and regular lists, but all have "Default Select List" in the BEF setting. Does this mean there is another setting somewhere that controls that?

Comment: Most likely it means that you have a filter that cannot be tweaked by BEF. Can you provide some details about your config? Also, D7 or D8? (D8 still has a lot of work before it's production ready.... But I always like to know where the bugs are!)

Comment: @mikeker I am just now getting back to this issue (had several projects that took priority over this). What additional detail would you like?

Comment: The site is D7.

Comment: For one, what type of field are you filtering on? If there is not a limited number of option in the filter (eg: it displays as a text field) then there's not much BEF can do to tweak the display.